# What Kind of Lighting Rig is This?

Tags: lighting, studio-lighting

I saw this lighting rig on a music video and it has had me intrigued as to what it is called. I am looking into building one but I would like to do more research before I jump into anything.

It looks to be three tube fluorescent lights in a triangle.

Comment: If it was in a music video, you'll probably have better luck on avp.se.

Comment: looks designed to light the face from all sides for close-ups, or fisheye lens situations

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like the grown-up version of a ring light, except made into a triangle because straight tubes are available.  I doubt that there's any magic behind its engineering other than "hey, what can we do with these tubes" and it turned out to work pretty well =)

If you wanted to experiment cheaply I wager than most 3D modeling packages can simulate a triangle made of tubes like this so you could previz what a real setup would look like.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a more photography-oriented tool like this, look at the [SaberStrip](http://www.saberstrip.com/). I've never used them so can't offer any experience details.